# Is the map $GL_n(\mathbb{Z})\to GL_n(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$ surjective?

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

Suppose $F$ is a field. I want to know whether the map $GL_n(GW(F))\to GL_n(W(F))$ is surjective, where $GW$ means Grothendieck-Witt and $W$ means Witt. In the case $F$ is algebraic closed, it reduces to the surjectivity of $GL_n(\mathbb{Z})\to GL_n(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$. I know the case $n=1$ is true.

Comment: In general, by the same simple argument as in the answer, the image of $GL_n(Z)\to GL_n(Z/mZ)$ is the seet of matrices with det $\pm 1$, and in particular it's surjective iff $m=2,3,4,6$.

Comment: @YCor, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/386807/is-the-map-gl-n-mathbbz-to-gl-n-mathbbz-2-mathbbz-surjective/386808#comment986262_386807), my [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/386808) used that $\operatorname{SL}_n(\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z)$ was generated by transvections, which I only know to be true for $m$ prime.  Is it true in general?

Comment: @LSpice Yes. By the Chinese Remainder Theorem, we can reduce to prime powers. The ring $\mathbb{Z}/p^k \mathbb{Z}$ is local and, if $R$ is local, then $SL_n(R)$ is generated by transvections.

Comment: @LSpice yes. The general case follows from the case when $m$ is a prime power by Chinese theorem. The case $m=p^k$ prime power is an induction on $k$ and one can boil down to a matrix of the form $I+p^{k-1}A$ with $A$ of trace zero, and one easily reduces to $A$ diagonal $(1,-1,0,\dots,0)$ which is easy to deal with.

Comment: Sketch of proof of claim about local rings: Recall that the matrices $\left[ \begin{smallmatrix} 0&1 \\ -1&0 \end{smallmatrix} \right]$ and $\left[ \begin{smallmatrix} u& 0 \\ 0& u^{-1} \end{smallmatrix} \right]$ are products of transvections (for $u$ any unit). Now, let $g$ be an $n \times n$ determinant $1$ matrix over a local ring $R$. There must be some entry $g_{ij}$ which is not in the maximal ideal, and hence a unit. Using the $2 \times 2$ matrices above, we can move that entry into position $(1,1)$ and make it be $1$. So we can assume that $g_{11}=1$.

Comment: Then, multiplying by transvections, we can make $g_{ik}=g_{ki}=0$ for $2 \leq k \leq n$. Now induct on $n$.

Comment: Ah, I saw the Chinese-Remainder-Theorem reduction, but got stuck on the prime-power case, which is embarrassing since I'm a $p$-adic analyst!  If one were inclined to overcomplicate things (and probably risk circular reasoning), I suppose that one could think of it in Hensel's-lemma terms of lifting points on smooth schemes from the residue field of a local field up to the ring of integers of the local field.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the question in your title, yes:  $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z) = \operatorname{SL}_n(\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)$ is generated by transvections, and these obviously lift to $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb Z)$.

Comment: This actually answers the surjectivity of $GL_n(GW(F))\to GL_n(W(F))$ since $GW(F)$ is determined by a fiber square $\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\leftarrow W(F)$!